# Why is my page displaying duplicate objects during pagination?

Tags: django, pagination, htmx

I've added in a sort-by dropdown option to my webpage but for some reason it's displaying duplicate objects on the page. Here's how the flow goes:

1. User lands on webpage and list of objects (these are posts from other users) are displayed. **This displays as expected**
2. User then changes the drop down to sort the posts by "newest" and the webpage is reloaded but the webpage is displaying 2 of each object/post.

home_page.html that the user lands on:

```
<div class="bg-grey-lighter flex flex-col mt-2 mb-2">
    <div class="container max-w-sm mx-auto flex-1 flex flex-col items-center justify-center px-2">
        <form action="{% url 'posts:dropdown_selected' %}" method="get" name="sort_form">
            <select class="rounded border-gray-200" name="sort_by" onchange="sort_form.submit()">
                <option id="" value="placeholder" disabled selected hidden>Sort By</option>
                <option value="most_supported">Most Supported</option>
                <option value="newest">Newest</option>
                <option value="oldest">Oldest</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
{% if home_search %}
    {% for post in object_list %}
        <div class="bg-grey-lighter flex flex-col mt-2 mb-2">
            <a href="{% url 'posts:post_detail' post.pk %}">
            <div class="container max-w-sm mx-auto flex-1 flex flex-col items-center justify-center px-2">
                <div class="bg-white px-6 py-8 rounded shadow-md text-black w-full">
                    <img
                        class="lg mb-6"
                        src=""
                        >
                    <h1 class="mb-8 text-3xl text-center">{{ post.title }}</h1>
                    <p class="text-gray-700 text-base">
                        {{ post.description }}
                    </p>
            </a>
                    <div class="relative flex-nowrap text-gray-500 mt-8 mb-0">
                        {% for tag in post.tags.all %}
                            <div class="ml-4 text-xs inline-flex items-center font-bold leading-sm uppercase px-3 py-1 bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 rounded-full">{{ tag }}</div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    {% include 'home_page_pagination.html' %}
{% endif %}
{% endblock content %}
</body>
</html>
```

The `home_search` variable will be false (as that's set to True when the user uses the search bar - not shown but works fine). Therefore the page will go to the include `home_page_pagination.html`, which is here:

```
{% for post in object_list %}
    {% if forloop.last %}
        <div class="bg-grey-lighter flex flex-col mt-2 mb-2" hx-get="{% url 'posts:home' %}?page={{ page_obj.number|add:1 }}" hx-trigger="revealed" hx-swap="afterend" hx-target="this" name="search">
    {% else %}
        <div class="bg-grey-lighter flex flex-col mt-2 mb-2">
    {% endif %}
            <a href="{% url 'posts:post_detail' post.pk %}">
            <div class="container max-w-sm mx-auto flex-1 flex flex-col items-center justify-center px-2">
                <div class="bg-white px-6 py-8 rounded shadow-md text-black w-full">
                    <img
                        class="lg mb-6"
                        src=""
                        >
                    <h1 class="mb-8 text-3xl text-center">{{ post.title }}</h1>
                    <p class="text-gray-700 text-base">
                        {{ post.description }}
                    </p>
            </a>
                    <div class="relative flex-nowrap text-gray-500 mt-8 mb-0">
                        {% for tag in post.tags.all %}
                            <div class="ml-4 text-xs inline-flex items-center font-bold leading-sm uppercase px-3 py-1 bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 rounded-full">{{ tag }}</div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

Then if the user selects the dropdown and sorts by one of the options, this goes to the dropdown_selected function in my `views.py`:

```
def dropdown_selected(request):
    selection = request.GET.get('sort_by')
    if selection == "most_supported":
        posts = Post.objects.annotate(n_supporters=Count('supporters')).order_by('-n_supporters')
        context = {'object_list': posts}

    elif selection == "newest":
        posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-date')
        context = {'object_list': posts}

    else: #must be "oldest" first selected
        posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('date')
        context = {'object_list': posts}

    return render(request, "home_page.html", context)
```

Which re-renders the `home_page.html` page, repeating the loop and therefore sorting the objects by the dropdown selection. I thought by re-rendering the whole page I would avoid duplication, the page should just reload with the ordered `object_list` that is returned by the `dropdown_selected` function.

[image: First load of homepage, no sorting. This works as expected]

[image: Dropdown option "most supported" selected, page refreshes and the objects are duplicated]

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of how it's displaying both normally and as duplicates?

Comment: Sure, I've added in both images, thanks

Comment: I have tried to replicate the behaviour you're getting but I'm having normal results: no duplicates and sorting works fine. I was wondering, did you intentionally use `htmx` for fetching the sorted `Posts`? Because I see a simple way to implement the behaviour you need using `htmx` and without needing to refresh the page.

Comment: How strange that yours works fine. Are you thinking use ```htmx``` when a user selects the drop down. So instead of rendering the whole ```home_page.html```, I just insert the ```posts``` into the page? If I was to do that I'd need to remove the posts from the current view wouldn't I, otherwise I'd still end up with duplication?

Comment: I don't think there should be any duplication with that implementation.

Comment: Maybe if I play around with the insert location, like ```afterend``` or something. I'll have a go and report back